# unable to get the authentication token using Box API V2

Tags: box-api

I Am executing the following url but it showing the "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing".

**This are the url's..**

https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=hSyLDUOK7TWFqq6xuqKHPyGYDCpA7nIE&client_id=myclient_id&client_secret=myclient_secret

https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token%3Fgrant_type%3Dauthorization_code%26code%3DhSyLDUOK7TWFqq6xuqKHPyGYDCpA7nIE%26client_id%3Dmyclient_id%26client_secret%3Dmyclient_secret

please help me,

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Box API v2 Documentation](http://developers.box.com/oauth/), you need to make a POST request - what you are doing is a GET request.

You can make a POST request either by using a browser extension like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) or by using `curl`

```
➜  ~  curl -X POST \
> -d grant_type=authorization_code \
> -d code=your_code \
> -d client_id=your_id \
> -d client_secret=your_secret \
> https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token
```